# how to improve the select query performence in oracle.but where clause having nvl function?

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my query:

```
select col1, col2, col3 
from table_name 
where nvl(cola, 1)=nvl(cola,1)
```

There is a regular index on `cola`. How can I improve performance without changing index?

Comment: There is no way  a regular index on just `cola` will be used. You need a function based index: `create index on table_name(nvl(cola,1))`

Comment: The posted query reduces to `where 1 = 1` which will always be true, so leads to a full table scan. While we do need to simplify our problem when posting to SO we shouldn't over simplify.

Comment: thanks.but already cola having normal index need not add extra index.is there any hint about performance in nvl()?

Comment: Again: a "normal" index on that column will not help and will never be used.

Comment: Why do you need to compare `cola` column with itself? As @APC has wrote  `nvl(cola, 1)=nvl(cola,1)` equal `1=1`.

Answer (score 0):

You should create function based index like this:

```
create index on table_name(nvl(cola,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add an index on nvl(cola, 1).